# Concatenated field conversion error when executing a view in Oracle

Tags: html, xml, oracle, plsql

I have a view (`DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC`) to be able to visualize the transactions in Oracle. This view makes use of those already existing in the system: `v$sql`, `V$SQLSTATS`, `v$sqlarea` and `gv$process`.

And the structure and type of columns was as follows:

[image]

I have a procedure that attempts to use such a view, format the output to a single `HTML` string under certain conditions, and send it via email. Here is a simple summary of that procedure:

```
DECLARE
    V_BODY_TEXT CLOB;
BEGIN
    select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,'
        <tr>
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SID))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SQL_ID))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(USERNAME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(ONAME))) || '</th> 
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(MACHINE))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(WAIT_CLASS))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(EVENT))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(MODULE))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(LOGON_TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(START_TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(TIME))) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SQL_TEXT))) || '</th>
        </tr>
    ','').extract('//text()')).getclobval()) x
    INTO V_BODY_TEXT
    FROM DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC WHERE "TIME" > 300;
               
END;
```

The error presented by the execution of the above code is because the concatenated result only admits 4000 characters and it doesn't matter if I try to cast (`TO_CLOB`) field by field or the entire concatenated string, I still get the same error every time. result size is exceeded:

[image]

About the above code, the use of the `TO_CLOB` function, is my last attempt to try to solve the problem.

Said error does not allow any "substring" or "len" type action to be applied to it either.

I've also tried creating a table with all the fields of type `CLOB`, then inserting the result of the view, and using the above procedure now with the table, but I keep getting the same error every time the generated html code exceeds 4000 characters.

Therefore, I go to this community to see what other options they give me to get out of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution I found to avoid the various restrictions of the functions used to generate `xml` code or converters like the `utl_i18n.unescape_reference` function, was to use a `loop` with `FOR`:

```
DECLARE
    V_BODY CLOB;
    V_TABLE_BODY CLOB := NULL;

BEGIN

    --> DataSource:
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT  SID,  
                SQL_ID,
                USERNAME,
                ONAME,
                MACHINE,
                WAIT_CLASS,
                EVENT,
                MODULE,
                LOGON_TIME,
                START_TIME,
                TIME,
                SQL_TEXT
        FROM    DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC
        WHERE   "TIME" > 300
    )
    LOOP
        --> Table Body:
        V_TABLE_BODY := V_TABLE_BODY ||
            '<tr>'||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SID)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SQL_ID)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.USERNAME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.ONAME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.MACHINE)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.WAIT_CLASS)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.EVENT)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.MODULE)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.LOGON_TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.START_TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.TIME)||'</td>' ||
                '<td>'||trim(r.SQL_TEXT)||'</td>' ||
            '</tr>';

    END LOOP;
    ----

    IF V_TABLE_BODY IS NOT NULL THEN
        --> HTML Body:
        V_BODY :=
        '
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>SID</th>  
                        <th>SQL_ID</th>  
                        <th>USERNAME</th>  
                        <th>ONAME</th> 
                        <th>MACHINE</th>  
                        <th>WAIT_CLASS</th>  
                        <th>EVENT</th>  
                        <th>MODULE</th>  
                        <th>LOGON_TIME</th>  
                        <th>START_TIME</th>  
                        <th>TIME</th>  
                        <th>SQL_TEXT</th>
                    </tr>' ||
                    V_TABLE_BODY || --> Table Body
                '</table>
            </body>
        ';
                    
    -- Send Mail:
    DB_ADMIN.USP_SEND_MAIL(V_BODY); --> Referential
        
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The xmlelement function only accepts up to 4000 characters if the initialization parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD, and 32767 characters if MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED, so there's no point in converting to CLOB that early in your process. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLELEMENT.html#GUID-DEA75423-00EA-4034-A246-4A774ADC988E).

Also, the utl_i18n.unescape_reference function only accepts VARCHAR2 input, not CLOB. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-721DF8FD-2DBE-4CFD-BCDE-656242BD497E). This is the most likely place your query is failing.

Try this, working exclusively with VARCHAR2, doing explicit conversions from NUMBER and DATE types, and saving the aggregation into the largest string to the very end:

```
DECLARE
    V_BODY_TEXT CLOB;
BEGIN
    select xmlagg(utl_i18n.unescape_reference(xmlelement(e,'
        <tr>
            <td>' || TO_CHAR(SID) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(SQL_ID)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(USERNAME)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(ONAME)) || '</th> 
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(MACHINE)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(WAIT_CLASS)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(EVENT)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(MODULE)) || '</th>  
            <td>' || TO_CHAR(LOGON_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') || '</th>  
            <td>' || TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'DD-MON-YYYY') || '</th>  
            <td>' || TO_CHAR(TIME) || '</th>  
            <td>' || ltrim(rtrim(TO_CLOB(SQL_TEXT))) || '</th>
        </tr>
    ',''))) x
    INTO V_BODY_TEXT
    FROM DB_ADMIN.VW_DBA_MONITOR_CURRENTLYEXEC WHERE "TIME" > 300;
           
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In this case the error seems to be due to incompatibility in the argument for the unescape_reference function:


`PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments when calling 'UNESCAPE_REFERENCE'`

`PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "UTL_I18N"."UNESCAPE_REFERENCE": invalid identifier`

I will keep looking for other options. Thansk

Comment: I removed the `.extract()` and `.getclobval()` references, as they did not appear to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

XMLType methods are [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/whatsnew.htm#ADXDB5941) since Oracle 11gr2, use modern (though, it's hard to tell about XML) SQL functions to access XML data without additional serialization/deserialization issues:

- [`XMLQUERY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html#GUID-9E8D3220-2CF5-4C63-BDC2-0526D57B9CDB) for extraction.
- [`XMLCAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLCAST.html#GUID-06563B93-1247-4F0C-B6BE-42DB3B1DB069) for deserialization. It does decoding of HTML/XML stuff like `&amp;` etc to their text values.

Below is an example of three characters padded with zeroes up to 5000 bytes (so resulting in too large value for `varchar2`)

```
with t(col) as (
  select
    xmlelement(e,
      to_clob(rpad('<>&', 4000, '0'))
      || to_clob(rpad('0', 1000, '0'))
    )
  from dual
)
, deser as (
  select
    xmlcast(xmlquery(
      '//text()'
      passing col
      returning content
    ) as clob) as res
  from t
)
select
  length(res),
  trim(trailing '0' from res) as res
from deser
```

| LENGTH(RES) | RES |
| --- | --- |
| 5000 | <>& |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HIaJUo6v)

However, you may avoid concatenation at all and serialize SQL result directly into XML with [`dbms_xmlgen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XMLGEN.html) package. Below is an example:

```sql
with function f_get_html(
  p_rows int
)
return clob
as
  l_ctx number;
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_res clob;
begin
  /* Cursor object is used to be able to use parameters for statement.
     In case of static statement may be replaced by string literal
     containing SQL statement directly in newcontext call
  */
  open l_cursor for
    select
      dummy as "td", level as "td",
      '<>&' as "td"
    from dual
    connect by level < p_rows
  ;
  /*Use context to set row tags to <tr>*/
  l_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(
    l_cursor
  );
  dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(l_ctx, 'tr');
  /*Extract content as HTML-formatted clob*/
  select xmlserialize(content xmlquery(
      '/ROWSET/*'
      passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(l_ctx)
      returning content
    ) as clob)
    into l_res
  from dual;
  
  return l_res;
end;

select f_get_html(4) as res_html
from dual
```

| RES_HTML |
| --- |
| <tr><td>X</td><td>1</td><td><>&</td></tr><tr><td>X</td><td>2</td><td><>&</td></tr><tr><td>X</td><td>3</td><td><>&</td></tr> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0AT8YawW)

Comment: thanks for answering. Your suggestion seems interesting to me. But one of the problems I've had, which is why I was forced to use the `utl_i18n.unescape_reference` function, was that these characters were generated: `&lt;&gt;&amp;` . How would you solve it?

Comment: @Fran.J As you may see, the generated HTML is correctly parsed by SO while it has `&lt;` etc in the raw data (you may run the code in a fiddle and see an output). You serialize generated HTML into XML (by using `XMLElement`), so if you have, for example `<` as a data, you need to have `<td>&lt;</td>` in HTML, which in turn will be converted into `<e>&lt;td&gt;&lt;&lt;/td&gt;</e>` in XML. When you apply `unescape...` it will return invalid HTML: `<td><</td>`, `XMLSerialize` will not.

Comment: You are right. Any web browser knows how to interpret those codes. My problem is that I view the `html` generated by Outlook and unfortunately it shows it as it is, it doesn't interpret it.